# I have faced warning and Error in useEffect() Function React Native app new 'NativeEventEmitter()'

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

**Given Error:**
This is the Image of the Error which I get when I run the app. You can see the image below.
[image]

**My useEffect Code**
Here is my useEffect function, I use Firestore to fetch the data about Post. Even post display inside the function but not show in the flatlist. But my main focus is to solve the error which is given below.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore().collection("Posts").onSnapshot(
    (querySnapshot) => {
      const data = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        try {
          const userDoc = await firestore().collection("Users").doc(await doc.data().uid).get();
          if (userDoc.exists) {
            const name = userDoc.data().name;
            const image = userDoc.data().image;
            data.push({ ...doc.data(), name, image });
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error getting user document:", error);
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      });

      setPost(data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error("Error in onSnapshot:", error);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  );

  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```